# MongoDB Query Or Condition Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have `status` collection which has four fields `abc, xyz, status, time`

I want to create MongoDB query for the below MySql query:

```
select * from status where abc = false and xyz = true and (status = pending or (status = inprogress and time = "2015-08-04"))
```

Basically `status` can be `pending` or `inprogress` but if it is `inprogress` then `time` must be compare.

I have tried to create below MongodDB query but it did not work

```
db.status.find
{   
    "abc" : false , 
    "xyz" : true , 
    "status" : "pending" , 
    "$and" : [ 
    { "status" : "inprogress"} , 
    { "time" : { "$eq" : { "$date" : "2015-08-04"}}}
    ]
}
```

I am using Spring MongoDB, I would appreciate if someone can guide me how to create it in Spring Data MongoDb.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There area couple of things wrong with the current query you are trying. The first thing to understand is that all operations are implicitly and "AND" condition unless stated otherwise. Therefore the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition that you are missing here must contain "both" of the status test and other combined "time" conditions like so:

```js
db.status.find({   
    "abc" : false, 
    "xyz" : true, 
    "$or" : [ 
        { "status" : "pending" },
        { 
           "status" : "inprogress"
           "time" : "2015-08-04"
        }
    ]
})
```

Your SQL representation here also implies that "time" is in fact a string. If it has been stored the same way in your MongoDB document then the above is fine. If not, and the values have been converted to actual `Date` objects in BSON, then you must supply a BSON date ( or something that converts ) as an argument. Typically dates are not "exact", so you use a "range" instead:

```js
db.status.find({   
    "abc" : false, 
    "xyz" : true, 
    "$or" : [ 
        { "status" : "pending" },
        { 
           "status" : "inprogress"
           "time" : { "$gte": new Date("2015-08-04"), "$lt": new Date("2015-08-05") }
        }
    ]
})
```

For spring translation that would be:

```js
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("abc").is(false)
    .and("xyz").is(true)
    .orOperator(
        Criteria.where("status").is("pending"),
        Criteria.where("status").is("inprogress")
            .and("time").is("2015-08-04")
    )
);
```

Or with real date object and a range:

```js
DateTime startDay = new DateTime(2015, 8, 4, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
Date startDate = startDay.toDate();
Date endDate = startDay.plusDays(1).toDate();

Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("abc").is(false)
    .and("xyz").is(true)
    .orOperator(
        Criteria.where("status").is("pending"),
        Criteria.where("status").is("inprogress")
            .and("time").gte(startDate).lt(endDate)
    )
);
```

At least from memory that should be correct, as sitting away from an IDE right now. Also note the "chaining" of operators here such as [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) also means an "AND" condition as assigned to the values of the same key.

When dealing with dates, the underlying driver expects all input to match a BSON date be cast as a [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) type from however you instantiate the date.

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted. One more question: what if `xyz`, `status`, `time` fields are not present in my `status` document, I still want to fetch the documents based on `abc` field. how can I do it in Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: @Nitesh If you have another question then [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as that is the best way to express your question clearly. Testing for fields present is done with the `$exists` operator.